# Tensorflow sparse to dense operations failing when placeholder provided shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I'm having an issue multiplying a sparse tensor (a sparse placeholder) by a dense tensor in Tensorflow. I am also encountering problems converting a sparse tensor to a dense tensor directly. I've searched but so far haven't found an example of this problem.

### TL;DR

The computation works if the sparse placeholder has its `shape` argument set to `None`, but if I provide a shape like `(3,3)` it fails.

Here is the code that works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

matrix_place = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="foo", shape=(3,2))
sparse_place = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, name="bar", shape=None) # Note shape is None

mul_result = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(sparse_place, matrix_place)

matrix_input = np.ones((3,2))
sparse_input = tf.SparseTensorValue([[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]], [1, 2, 3], (3, 3))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(mul_result, feed_dict={sparse_place: sparse_input, matrix_place: matrix_input})
    print(result)
```

Output (as expected):

```
[[1. 1.]
 [2. 2.]
 [3. 3.]]
```

Now, if I change this line:

```
sparse_place = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, name="bar", shape=None)
```

to this:

```
sparse_place = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, name="bar", shape=(3,3))
```

(which matches the shape of the `tf.SparseTenorValue(...)` that I'm feeding in), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing_sparse3.py", line 13, in <module>
    result = sess.run(mul_result, feed_dict={sparse_place: sparse_input, matrix_place: matrix_input})
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1115, in _run
    raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("bar/shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64) may not be fed.
```

### Things I've Tried

If I switch from matrix multiplication (which involves 2 tensors):

```
sparse_place = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, name="bar", shape=(3,3))

mul_result = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(sparse_place, matrix_place)
```

to simply summing the elements of the sparse tensor (which only involves the sparse tensor):

```
sparse_place = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, name="bar", shape=(3,3))

mul_result = tf.sparse_tensor_reduce_sum(sparse_place)
```

it does not produce an error and gives the correct result. But if I try to convert the sparse tensor to a dense tensor (an op which also only involves the sparse tensor):

```
sparse_place = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, name="bar", shape=(3,3))

mul_result = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_place)
```

the error returns.

I did see a [related](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6749) issue but it appears to have been [merged](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/11153) already. I tried converting the indices/values/shape passed to `tf.SparseTensorValue` into numpy arrays with dtypes `int64`/`float32`/`int64` respectively, but the problem persisted. I also tried converting the `(3,3)` shape passed to the sparse placeholder into a numpy `int64` array but that also failed.

Any ideas? Am I missing something very obvious? I am using Python 3.5 and Tensorflow v1.6.0 (CPU) on Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `shape = (3, 3)` TensorFlow treats that shape as a constant for shape inference, and disallows feeding that shape tensor. We should probably detect that you're feeding its actual value and let it pass. File a github issue.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Based on your reply I found a workaround. Instead of using
`tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, dense_shape)`, Tensorflow also allows a tuple `(indices, values, dense_shape)`. In the case where the shape is already provided to the placeholder, a tuple with just `(indices, values)` seems to work. I'll file a github issue. Thanks again.